# Errors building tests trying to use Magical Record with Kiwi

Tags: ios, core-data, sentestingkit, magicalrecord

I'm having problems getting Magical Record to play nicely with a testing target that's based on Kiwi.   Kiwi's been set up as per the process on the GitHub wiki; Magical Record works fine on the other targets and I'm including the CoreData+MagicalRecord headers at the start of each test file

The build fails with 4 errors in NSObject+MagicalDataImport - it's not recognising NSAttributeDescription as a type.

I can work around this by explicitly including the Core Data headers, but that then provokes another series of errors with the categories on NSPersistentStore, NSPersistentStoreCoordinator, NSManagedObjectContext and iCloud.

I'm guessing that it's something to do with the way or the order in which the frameworks are included in the test targets - but these look the same as the other targets in the project, which work fine.

Does anyone know what the process for getting Magical Record to play nicely with Kiwi *should* be??

Comment: This turned out to be user error - I'd neglected to add CoreData+MagicalRecord.h to the testing target's .pch file. When included properly, everything works just as it should...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure I did something special, but I have it working.  All I did was use Cocoapods.